# Adding custom javascript to Magento 2 to be use in both product and category page

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery

I am trying to **add custom javascript to all product page and category page**. but I don't known if to create custom magento 2 module or can edit the magento vendor module.

If I can use the two above how do i go about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code in app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{ThemePackage}/Magento_Catalog/view/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <!-- some code-->

        <!-- for including css -->
        <css src="Magento_Catalog::css/some.css"/>     
        <!-- for including js -->

        <link src="Magento_Catalog::js/slider/some.js"/>

        <!-- some code-->
    </head>
</page>
```

Comment: for my default theme I don't have view folder and default.xml on that directory. Can I use custom module

Comment: If you are using any theme Please create these directories and file  else create a module

Comment: I am thinking of future where we may update the theme

Comment: Module creation is the best part for that also this xml work

Comment: How can I do this with custom module